# How to add consul registry in istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, consul

I want to add a consul registry in istio, but the istio documentation only has the `pilot-discovery discovery` command with the parameters:

```
--consulserverURL <string>
--registries <stringSlice>
```

But I don’t know how to write command line parameters into the configuration file, and the istio document does not describe how to do this.

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/pilot-discovery/) you can use

```
pilot-discovery discovery [flags]
```

Pilot is part of [istiod](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/istiod/) now, so you can get your istio pods with

```
kubectl get pods -n istio-system
```

Use [kubectl exec](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_exec/) to get into your istiod container with

```
kubectl exec -ti <istiod-pod-name> -c discovery -n istio-system -- /bin/bash
```

Use above pilot-discovery command with appropriate flags

e.g.

```
pilot-discovery discovery --consulserverURL="asd.x.svc:9999" --registries="{Kubernetes,Consul}"

2020-09-01T09:16:43.528744Z     info    FLAG: --consulserverURL="asd.x.svc:9999"
2020-09-01T09:16:43.529136Z     info    FLAG: --registries="[{Kubernetes,Consul}]"
```

Comment: This is indeed possible, but I want to write the parameters in the istio configuration file instead of manually executing it after the pod is started. Is there a better way?
I have tried to modify the chart under manifests, but no effect.

Comment: @Souther Dawn I couldn't find any other way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am still trying other way